# Implementing simple shell

Tags: c

I try to implement a simple shell. I want, that my program can execute commands from shell like:  **.\cmd1 ; .\cmd2**. I know how to execute only one program .\cmd1 or .\cmd2 with **execvpe**, but how can I make that my program execute both program calls(cmd1 and cmd2).

Comment: `.\cmd1; .\cmd2` are, in common shells, two commands run one after the other. So execpve() or whatever is ok: good for one command, good for two. You need to parse the command line given as input to your shell and recognize the `;` to separate two commands.

Answer (score 0):

create a file.sh with ur commands in it

./cmd1
./cmd2

save file.sh, and run it from ur terminal, ./file.sh
it should execute the commands inside it

Comment: This answer seems quite deviating from what the OP asks.

Comment: @АлександарСтојичић - if you figured that out, it is a good idea to post an answer to your question describing the solution, and to mark the question as solved.